# Search not working in site collection (I created a new search service app and did full crawl)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, service-application

I am trying to learn Search and this is what I did but when I search something in my site collection, it shows no results.

**Site Collection**

- Created a new team site
- Enabled major/minor version on "Shared Document" library
- Uploaded "expense_report.rtf" as minor version
- Uploaded "hr_policy.rtf" as major (published) version

**Search service application**

- Created a new domain user account for search named "my_search"
- Created new search service application and used that account which I created in first step
- Service application successfully created
- Added a new "Website" as content source and gave URL of my site collection
- Started full crawl which it did

Now when I went back into my site collection and search for e.g. "expense" or "expense_report" or "hr_policy" then it doesn't bring any results.

I thought may be search domain user doesn't have permission so I went into my "Site Settings --> Site Permission" and gave READ permissions to "my_search" by adding it into "Visitors" group.

Then I started full crawl again and after crawl is finished, I search again in my site but same problem i.e. no results are shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried wether the user **my_search** can see the document in the site?

Comment: Yes. When I log in as "my_search" then I am able to read documents.

Comment: Have you reviewed the steps here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597.aspx

Comment: Are is the searchable items count in the search service application > 0 ? Do you get results with the content access account?

Comment: In Central Administration after Full Crawl you should be able to see Number of items searchable.. See if that count increased from zero.. If not that, than you can make Search Scope specific with the URL to your document library and then perform Full Crawl, the Scope after crawl will show items searchable within the Scope! Also if you are using any Proxy in your environment you need to provide the proxy, the option is available on Central Administration Search dashboard!

Comment: Yes I can see that crawl log shows 452 items crawled. But this looks like some permission issue. Since I am using my own search service application instead of the one provided by SharePoint hence some problem. I tested it with default search application and it worked fine.